# RestClient doesn't contain definition for BaseUrl and no accessible extension method BaseUrl accepting a first argument of type RestClient found

Tags: c#, salesforce, restsharp

I'm new to programing and I'm having some difficulty with something I'm trying to do - trying to write code in C# to get contacts stored in a MongoDB DB back into Salesforce,
there is an error about the **BaseUrl** in the code,
I got the code from Bing AI chat - that is mostly ok, but for the line of the BaseUrl I cant seem to find a solution, and I don't even know what the problem with it is, - I tried looking around a lot and asking Bing AI numerous questions from different aspects of the problem, but just couldn't find a solution for it.
can someone figure it out - what should I be writing different?

this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;


namespace SalesforceToMongoDB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Salesforce
            var client = new RestClient("https://login.salesforce.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/services/oauth2/token", Method.Post);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "your_client_id");
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", "your_client_secret");
            request.AddParameter("username", "your_username");
            request.AddParameter("password", "your_password");

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            string accessToken = (string)obj["access_token"];

            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://your-instance.lightning.force.com");
            request = new RestRequest("/services/data/v50.0/query/?      q=SELECT+FirstName,LastName,Email+FROM+Contact", Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            response = client.Execute(request);
            obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            var contacts = new List<BsonDocument>();
            foreach (var record in obj["records"])
            {
                var contact = new BsonDocument();
                contact.Add("FirstName", record["FirstName"].ToString());
                contact.Add("LastName", record["LastName"].ToString());
                contact.Add("Email", record["Email"].ToString());
                contacts.Add(contact);
            }

            // Connect to MongoDB
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("SFContacts");
            var mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Contacts");

            // Insert contacts into MongoDB
            mongoCollection.InsertMany(contacts);
        }
    }
}
```

when looking for a solution I kept being told to install- and after that didn't help - to uninstall and re install again this C# using :`using RestSharp;`
but it did not help - I have it installed, and it didn't change anything.
and also I tried to use this code instead

```
RestClient cli = new RestClient("https://your-instance.develop.lightning.force.com");
            RestRequest requ = new RestRequest("/services/data/v50.0/query/?q=SELECT+FirstName,LastName,Email+FROM+Contact", Method.GET);
            RestResponse resp = cli.Execute(requ);
```

and other pieces of code that I cant find right now but neither did they help,
the visual studio just doesn't seem to like any suggestion I got and tried.

Comment: What version of RestSharp are you using?  Their API has changed a lot over the years (see [here](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107)) so LLMs are likely poor sources of information for RestSharp as they will mix content from different versions with outright hallucinations.

Comment: Assuming you are using an up-to-date version of ResSharp (current version is 110.2.0), I would ignore any and all fabrications from Bing AI and other LLMs.  Instead, read through RestSharp's [Recommended usage](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#recommended-usage) documentation page, which gives step-by-step guidance for making a Twitter client.  Making a lightning.force.com client should basically parallel that.  Give it a try, then ask additional questions if you get stuck.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to read the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev) than relying on  Bing API to produce working code. To be fair, the first part where you get the token is completely legit.

However, the `BaseUrl` isn't supposed to be replaced. You are creating a new client, for a different base URL, which might have a completely different set of options.

Create a new client for the new base URL instead of changing the base URL, and it will work. You should at all costs avoid sending auth calls *every time*. The token you get has an expiration, so it should be used until it expires.

You can also look at the Twitter client implementation in RestSharp tests, which includes an authenticator. It's almost the same as Salesforce, you only need to add client id and secret to request parameters.